# Java WebDriver - Utilizing blocking time of WebElement.submit()

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Short version: WebElement.submit() is blocking; thus I can't utilize the time page being rendered to do something else.

---

Long version:

I'm using WebDriver Java Client Library 2.16.1

I have an automated test current done serially but can be done in parallel (basically log in to n different users to check status). Thus I'm trying use Thread to make it run concurrently: fire up multiple instances of Firefox at the same time.

The example code:

```
public class FirefoxRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        WebDriver d = new FirefoxDriver();
        d.get("http://www.facebook.com");
        d.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("username");
        d.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("password");
        d.findElement(By.id("pass")).submit();
    }
}

public static void test() {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new FirefoxRunnable("Thread 1"));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new FirefoxRunnable("Thread 2"));
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
```

Problem: `d.findElement(By.id("pass")).submit()` is blocking while the page is being loaded.

Any suggestion on how to utilize the time page being loaded to do something useful?

Answer (score 0):

You can not actually. Ultimately d.findElement(By.id("pass")).submit() has to be executed by CPU and if its a blocking call then it is going to utilize CPU (I am talking all this in context of single core). However modern OS will give a time slice to each thread so this is not necessary that from start to end all the time will be taken up by d.findElement(By.id("pass")).submit(). CPU will basically give your other threads and parent thread chance to execute.

Comment: I actually think it's blocking because it's implemented by a busy-wait loop, waiting until browser finishes loading the page and returns.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than submit , you can alternatively simulate Keypress "Keys.ENTER", which wont be blocking, and then you can explicit wait or find_element body tag (or any method that dont block) in ur sleep loop e.g >

```
for loop{
   if not found() //found (e.g findElement(body)) is non blocking, make sure no implicit wait
        sleep(3 secs)  // while sleep utilize this time
 }
```